# Which episode did Kyouko gave the charm to Tsuna?

Tags: reborn

In which episode did Kyouko gave the charm to Tsuna in *Kateikyoushi Hitman Reborn*?

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga, please use correct tags when next you post a question rather that try and use popular tags to get more views

Answer (score 2):

The episode is **Target 55: Resolution**. At **17:45** she gives to Tsuna. [YouTube](http://youtu.be/R6v6Z90LYps?t=16m)

In case the video is deleted, below is the picture where she shows the charms she made for everyone.

[image: Charm for all]

I wanted to add a screenshot when she was giving charm to Tsuna, but I cannot find Tsuna,  the charm and Kyouko all in a single picture.